# Xcode drawInRect split the String depending on RectSize

Tags: xcode, pdf, dynamic, split, drawinrect

I would like to create a pdf dynamically. But I have problems with new pages.

Currently I am writing a text block and if that text block does not fit to the remaining Y position - I write the whole text block on a new page.
But I would like to take the whole text block, write to the actual page as much as I can and write the rest on a new page. Does someone know how to split the text in a rect depending on the rect size?

Thats the code:
writeString ist coming from CoreData and has a dynamic length.

```
    func drawTextBlock(pdfFileName: String, writeString: NSString = " ", fontSize: CGFloat = 12.0, fontName: String = "Helvetica", textAlignment: NSTextAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Natural) {

    //Text attribute configuration
    let font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)

    let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    textStyle.alignment = textAlignment

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: font!,
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle
    ]
    let textSize = writeString.sizeWithAttributes(textFontAttributes)

    let linesNeeded = ceil(textSize.width / (myPageCalibration.pageWidth  - myPageCalibration.xOffsetLeft - myPageCalibration.xOffsetRight))


    if remainingSpaceY >= (textSize.height * linesNeeded) {
        //draw text in rectangle
        writeString.drawInRect(CGRectMake(myPageCalibration.xOffsetLeft, myPageCalibration.yOffsetUp + currentPositionY, myPageCalibration.pageWidth - myPageCalibration.xOffsetLeft - myPageCalibration.xOffsetRight, (textSize.height * linesNeeded )), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

        //calc remainingSpace
        currentPositionY = CGFloat(linesNeeded * textSize.height) + currentPositionY
        remainingSpaceY = remainingSpaceY - (textSize.height * linesNeeded)
    }
    else {
        //next page
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 595, 842), nil);
        remainingSpaceY = myPageCalibration.pageHeight - myPageCalibration.yOffsetDown - myPageCalibration.yOffsetUp
        currentPositionY = 0

        drawTextBlock(pdfFileName, writeString: writeString, fontSize: fontSize, fontName: fontName, textAlignment: textAlignment)
    }
}
```